# Can a perfect circle encompassing face be formed using euler angle in face detector

Tags: android, eclipse, face-detection

I have following code:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
        {
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            paint.setColor(Color.RED);

            xRatio = getWidth()*1.0f / picWidth;
            yRatio = getHeight()*1.0f / picHeight;                      
            canvas.drawBitmap( sourceImage, null , new Rect(0,0,getWidth(),getHeight()),paint);

            for (int i = 0; i < eyesMidPts.length; i++)
            {
                if (eyesMidPts[i] != null)
                {
                    // where x and y are eyes mid point coordinates

                    float x = eyesMidPts[i].x*xRatio;
                    float y = eyesMidPts[i].y*yRatio;
                    float radius = (float) (eyesDistance[i]);
                    float left =  x - radius;
                    float right = x + radius;
                    float top = y - radius;
                    // we want to increase the bottom radius by double to get other half of the face.
                    float bottom = (float) (y + radius * 2);                    

                    paint.setStrokeWidth(eyesDistance[i] /20);                  
                    RectF ovalBounds = new RectF();
                    ovalBounds.set(left, top, right, bottom);                                                       
                    canvas.drawOval(ovalBounds, paint);                                     
                }
            }           
        }
```

Code encompass full face if face is straight. But does not get complete circle around if face is tilted. I am not sure how euler angels work but am hoping it is to get tilt on the face detection. Can someone please help me with this show me some example code so that circle encompasses whole face.

Comment: If you're identifying the positions of the eyes already, can you not just calculate the angle between them and then rotate the circle by the same amount?

Comment: @OGHaza - Can you show me how i can do this in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you use RectF to draw a circle? Is it a 'true' circle, or is it really oval / ellipse?

If it's just a circle, why don't you use [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawCircle%28float,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint%29).

```
canvas.drawCircle(x, y, radius, paint);
```

So you won't need to transform Rectf's points if it's tilted :)

*update*:

I believe this should work, I don't have an android workflow setup with me to really test it; sorry if it's a miss.

```
Matrix m = new Matrix(); //creates identity matrix
m.setRotate(tilt_angle); //rotate it by the tilt angle
m.mapRect(ovalBounds); //transform the rect
```

Comment: Reason for that is if face is tilted towards bottom more. Circle will not get lips correctly. That is why want to use eular angles to get complete face inside the circle or ellipse.

Comment: Well, you should know that. You mentioned it, I didn't.

Comment: Don't tell me you need to encompass the face if the head is tilted? I thought you're looking for a correction when the phone is tilted. If that's the case, then I can't help you. Seems like a very non-trivial task.

Comment: Please read the title i am looking to get eular angles and make circle according to that.

Comment: Euler angles of what? I've read the title; you should have been more specific on your part.

Comment: @NoviceMe Euler angles imply you are trying to get the absolute orientation of the persons head in 3d space, unless you're using a 3d camera I doubt this is the case so the terminology is only likely to confuse.

Comment: @iccthedral - Sorry about that but here is little more info: Eular angles of face if it is tilted and draw circle according to that.

Comment: @OGHaza - Sorry i might be wrong but is there any other way to do this for titled face?

Comment: Did you read my comment on your question? Lets not have this chat on iccthedral's post.

Answer (score 0):

```
// RectF face: face position and dimentions

// Create Bitmap where to draw an oval
Bitmap ovalBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap( face.width(), face.height(), config );
canvasBmp = new Canvas(ovalBmp); // Get a canvas to draw an oval on the Bitmap
canvasBmp.drawOval( new RectF( 0, 0, face.width(), face.height ), paint );

// Create transformation matrix
transforMatrix = new Matrix();
// Rotate around center of oval
transforMatrix.postRotate( tilt_angle, face.width() / 2, face.height() / 2 );
transforMatrix.postTranslate( face.left, face.top );
canvas.drawBitmap( ovalBmp, transforMatrix, null );
```

ps: I assume by *tilt* angle you mean *roll*, where *pitch* is rotation around X axis, *yaw* is rotation around Y axis and *roll* is rotation around Z axis.